# Why is my loading indiactor not updated by change detection?

Tags: angular

I have a basic component as an example.
I simulate a request which has a loading time of 4 seconds.
During the loading time I want to display a loading indicator.

But however, this loading indicator won't be displayed for OnPush on the first initial run.
After pressing the reload button manually, everthing works as expected.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic {
  reload$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0);
  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  data$ = this.reload$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.fetchData()));

  fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.loading$.next(true);

    return of([]).pipe(
      delay(4000),
      finalize(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="loading$ | async">Loading...</div>
<button type="button" (click)="reload$.next()">reload</button>
<div *ngIf="data$ | async">
  <!-- show rows -->
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzkjlq?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-basic.html,src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-basic.ts

What is the problem here? Why is there no loading indicator for the first run?
I thought the async pipe should trigger a change detection when loading$ gets a new value emitted?

Comment: The provided example on Stackblitz seems to work fine, also for the initial run. Could you please double check that?

Comment: the first run should be executed during initialization of the page automatically (I'm using a BehaviorSubject for that). So even without clicking the reload button, the loading indicator should be displayed initially for the first 4 seconds

Comment: Yes, exactly the async pipe will trigger the detection cycle but you are using Subject which only emits value in your case in the fetchData() method. Try using BehaviorSubject for loading$ and give it an initial value of true, that would work even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: But why isn't it working when I use a Subject or a BehaviorSubject with initival value to false? As soon as the loading indicator will be emitted with true, the loading indicator should be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

### Initial answer

I see where the problem is. Your code is functional as-is. You just forgot to subscribe to your `data$`. Please find below the code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic implements OnInit {
  reload$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0);
  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  data$ = this.reload$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.fetchData()));

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$.subscribe();  // subscribe to data$
  }

  fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.loading$.next(true);

    return of([]).pipe(
      delay(4000),
      finalize(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    );
  }
}
```

Please feel free to use a cleaner method to subscribe to `data$`. And also handle the unsubscription. You should also remove the `changeDetection`.

### Updated answer

I totally missed that you have subscribed to `data$` in your HTML already. In that case please simply remove the `changeDetection` from your original code and you should see the behavior you are expecting:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic {
  reload$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0);
  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  data$ = this.reload$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.fetchData()));

  fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.loading$.next(true);

    return of([]).pipe(
      delay(4000),
      finalize(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzkjlq-aeqmqr?file=src/app/accordion-basic.ts)

Comment: No the subscription is in the template by using the async pipe.

Comment: @user2622344 My bad I missed that part. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but there must be a solution for OnPush components? I need the OnPush, because my real component has a lot of logic and I can't afford to run the change detection too often.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "little shit", but you can solve adding a delay(0) in your data$

```
data$= this.reload$.pipe(delay(0),
                         switchMap(() => this.fetchData()));
```

Or in your loading$

```
  loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable().pipe(delay(0))

  fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
      delay(4000),
      finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }
```

You can also Inject the ChangeDetectorRef in constructor

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

And use

```
fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.loading$.next(true);
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); //<--Add this line
    return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
      delay(4000),
      finalize(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    );
  }
```

NOTE: Really I don't know the reason. Furthermore, if you put the loading after the data looks like work without change

```
<button type="button" (click)="reload$.next()">reload</button>
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as  data">
  <!-- show rows -->
  {{data}}
</div>
<!--the loading after the data$|async-->
<div *ngIf="loading$ | async">Loading...</div>
```